# Links are invisible on the Main site

Tags: discussion, feature-request, status-completed, design, hyperlinks

I've noticed this for quite some time, but I suppose the time has come to do something about it. At least for me to speak about it, hoping to cause some change.

Links on TeX SE Main are invisible. Hard to locate unless you really put the cursor on. The color is a blue so dark it's almost black and it basically blends with the rest of the text. This is how it looks on Tex, can you see them?

> [image]

If you couldn't see them fast enough, there's a problem. There were three links in that screenshot. Here's where they are:

> [image]

And here's the text version, if you want to test it:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec lacus eros, 
pellentesque vel elit at, pretium porttitor nulla. Vestibulum eget quam vitae nisi 
semper sagittis sit amet [sed dui](http://tex.stackexchange.com/).
Curabitur elit neque, ultricies sit amet dictum nec, molestie non leo. 
Ut pellentesque lectus quam, at posuere nibh hendrerit sit amet. 
Vivamus [at](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) condimentum odio. Mauris 
pulvinar [ligula](http://tex.stackexchange.com/) a ornare accumsan. 
Aliquam consequat vitae nibh in feugiat.
```

In comparison others sites have much more visible links, and that's how it should be. I picked two examples from non-beta sites, because the beta sites have very bright blue links and they are all visible, while on non-beta sites, themes change and we can see various versions. And that's another point: why are the links on this site *blue* when the theme is mostly yellowish with some maroon and red?

### Skeptics SE

> [image]

### English Language & Usage

> [image]

Comment: can you give a link to a question or answer on tex.sx that has links?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Would it be the same if I provided the text above with the same links? That way you can paste it when pretending to ask a question and see the preview.

Comment: abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og) abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og) abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og) abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og) abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og) abc [xyz](http://somewhere.og)

Comment: ^^^ OK here they are rust coloured but on the main site they are blue with less contrast I agree

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Yes, here they are visible. :D I have added the example text to the question above, if you wish to test it.

Comment: A real life example: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/116071/autocomplete-problem-in-texstudio-2-3?lq=1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks for your input. We've adjusted the links and they are now red.

Comment: Looking at a question, all related questions are in the usual orange-brown, and suddenly the hot posts from  other sites appear in red. Almost like stealing the show. Same for names on main, which kind of steal the show to the tags (greatfully acknowledging that they are not bold +1).

Comment: @Johannes_B Looking into it.

Comment: That's a good point. Maybe not *all* links have to be red(dish)? If all the links stay as they did, except the ones in the text bodies (answers, questions, comments), maybe that would work better? Not sure if it's easily doable though.

Comment: Now also several parts of code snippets became red. Is Dracula the new leader of the group in charge of site design? `;-)`

Answer (score 3):

When the sites were recently re-designed across the network, a lot of them were left with standard blue links and blue coloring for elements like the bounty count (from Stack Overflow, I guess). In some cases -- like TeX.SE -- the blue color doesn't go well with the site.<sup>1</sup>

Because of this, I wrote myself some user styles to override these blue links on various sites I use across the SE network. TeX.SE is one of them (I actually hadn't noticed the problem you pointed out because I had modified the link colors already), and here is a user style to improve the link colors (this also affects meta.tex.stackexchange.com):

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("tex.stackexchange.com") {
  /* Red for most links (link is already underlined when the mouse hovers over it) */
  a, a:hover { color: rgb(180, 50, 50); }

  /* Brown for visited links in posts only */
  .post-text a:visited { color: rgb(188, 124, 61); }

  /* More links to color red (e.g. username links and mod diamonds) */
  .started a:not(.started-link), .started a:hover:not(.started-link), span.mod-flair, .started .mod-flair, .started .mod-flair:hover {
    color: rgb(180, 50, 50);
  }

  /* Red for bounty related elements to match main link color */
  .bounty-indicator, .bounty-indicator-tab, span.bounty-award { background-color: rgb(180, 50, 50); }

  /* Match the community bulletin background color with the highlight color for questions that use a followed tag */
  .module.community-bulletin, .module.newuser {
    background-color: rgba(236, 225, 194, 0.25);
    border: 1px solid rgb(235, 235, 235);
  }
}
```

Here is a before and after comparison of the link colors from [an example post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116076/61108) (one link has been visited, the other has not):

[image: TeX SE before]

[image: TeX SE after]

I chose the colors in an effort to try to match the site design. Here is a screenshot of my view of the main page:

[image: TeX SE main]

Of course, you can change these colors if they don't work for you.

There is a nice [set of instructions on using user styles on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/465964/474180).

Hopefully this workaround will help you and others until SE decides (if ever) to change the colors as you requested.

---

<sup>1</sup>Another example is EE.SE:

[image: EE SE]

EE.SE was re-designed to use orange as its main color (notice the logo and the "sign up for the newsletter" button) but still uses blue for its links.

Comment: Would the same instructions work for Chrome?

Comment: @Alenanno My understanding from the SuperUser post I linked to is that there is a Stylish extension for Chrome as well (see the last paragraph of the post). The only difference is that you enter the URL differently. So you would enter the URL as Chrome requires and then enter the code I posted but with the `@-moz-document domain("tex.stackexchange.com") {` and its closing brace deleted.