# New top bar... feedback?

Tags: discussion, design, top-bar

The [new top bar is live](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/301845/168244) and has been receiving mixed reviews after its [initial anouncement](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/300829/168244).

There are some things that are network wide that will most like not change (deemed [status-bydesign](/questions/tagged/status-bydesign)), but anything specific to TeX.SE and it's child meta can be addressed here.

Comment: Probably not site specific (no idea, really), but does chat still exist? No idea how to get there any longer.

Comment: @cfr: Yes, it still exists. You'll find it [in the hamburger menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Oi2Dz.png).

Comment: Ta. And some more.

Comment: Also, my potion has turned very green. But I'm not sure whether to blame that on SE or not :-).

Answer (score 16):

It is now really hard to see if there is something in the review queue. There is no notification on the symbol itself and after clicking on it, the only indication is a pale grey dot on a pale background:

[image]

Comment: and certainly the icons themselves will take some getting used to.  i don't find them particularly obvious, although that could be an indication that, once again, i need new glasses.

Comment: Our review queues have very little in them usually. The review queue on [SO](//stackoverflow.com) is far more lively. For "some content" in a queue, the button is gray. For "lots of content" in a queue, the button is red. [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MxSsW.png). They've had difficulty in the past keeping the queue counts accurate. My guess is this colour-coded view is a subtle way of ignoring the counts in lieu of providing a "flag", *per se*.

Answer (score 15):

yet another case of

[image]

Answer (score 12):

The red colour of the textual highlights across the main site work on a light background, but is difficult to read on the black top bar, and becomes almost illegible upon hovering:

[image]

Related: Historically we used to have [blue textual highlights/links](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6451/5764), which were subsequently [changed to red](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6529/5764).

Comment: This is clearly a bug. Working on fix right now.

Comment: @ebo Imgur seems to be struggling at the moment.

Comment: Yesterday the logo colour was blue. I'm curious what tomorrows colour will be :)

Comment: Mine is blue. Did I miss the red?

Comment: @cfr: Indeed. The red (and all the other colours across all the other sites) was a bug. It was orange on Meta.TeX... :-/

Comment: @Werner Can we get the bug back for Halloween?

Comment: @Werner I would rather say it was using site's main highlight color (i.e. just like regular hyperlinks): they are red on TeX.SE yet orange here on meta.TeX.SE. (This "theory" appeared to be true in the other few x.SE sites I checked)

Answer (score 10):

> **Issue now solved, thanks to an update of the top-bar**

I would like to emphasis the fact that the choice of the red color for the StackExchange logo is not, imho, very successful.

[image]

Indeed, due to the red color, every time my eye comes closer to the top-left region, it triggers something in my mind like *"I got a message / there is an error / Something has to be done..."* which is quite disturbing on the long run.

I would rather suggest a more "neutral" color, e.g. something close to the brown-yellowish background of TeX.SE.

Comment: On a side note, even if I get the concept of customizing this logo with the color template of each x.SE site, the per-site color-change does not seems *semantically* correct to me. Indeed, this button redirects to SE.com, whatever the site it is on. I think it would then have been more consistent to appear identical on each x.SE site at it has an identical effect -- and not a similar-but-customized effect depending on the x.SE site it is on.

Comment: on my screen, the *stackexchange* logo is still white "stack" and blue "exchange" on a black background.  it's the *tex* logo that's red.  (im working on a windows/professional workstation, with firefox 54.0.)  is this color scheme different on other browsers?

Comment: @barbarabeeton Indeed: It was red earlier today (see gif on [Werner's answer](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/a/7437/64454)), yet was updated (see [TeXnician's comment](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7436/new-top-bar-feedback/7438?noredirect=1#comment22156_7439)) later on. **This issue is thus now solved.**

Answer (score 3):

Apart from the ugly color of the word "StackExchange", I would have preferred to have the search field on the right.

Comment: And I would prefer a smaller (height) search field, but that is not site-specific (by design, see question).

Comment: @TeXnician Ops... I leave my answer, anyway, maybe it could be a signal :):):)

Comment: @TeXnician but has the color changed now?

Comment: Yes, it has changed.

Comment: I would have preferred a better `Search` usability at all ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer: You can install a [userscript](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/301909/168244) that allows some historic flexibility.